# How to approach this Asp.Net web api security issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I've build an Asp.Net web api for being able to make ajax calls from my app to my database thru this api. There is this specific column called "likes" that i'm concerned about since it's a public api i dont want people to be able to just make an http call to update the "likes" value to whatever value they want to. My app makes sure that they only can like something once. My question is unfortunately not that specific because i simply dont know how to specify it, but does anyone have any idea of how to approach this? I checked into authorization, tokens, ssl etc, but it feels like there must be a shorter way for this problem with denying people to update this column outside of the app? Any help highly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the username or unique user identifier to the `likes` API endpoint. Then on the server side, you can validate the user exists and only allow them to like something once. Any additional requests from that user to like the same item can be ignored.

Comment: good answer. the only way you can verify that an api request like this is legitimate is by expecting some "secret" to be passed from one side to another. there's no shorter way around that.

Comment: Thanks kevin, that got me thinking in another direction that might work, going to try it out tomorrow :)